# Dynamic and multiple values in relational database

Tags: sql, mongodb

In my relational database, I want to store details about users (`firstName`, `lastName`, `email`...). So this means I have a `Users` table.

These fields can change in the future (ca be added/removed), and not all users have the same details - for example some users might not have `email`).

This data is collected from the user on different occasions when they submit some form.

I want to be able to store, for example, all of the forms the user entered their first name ("Mike", "mike", "Michael", "michael", etc.), and how many times they entered it that way.

Options:

1. In my `Users` table, have multiple columns/fields, each storing a string encoded JSON object (e.g. `{"Mike": 5, "Michael": 3}`. That's bad for obvious reasons.
2. Add another table with one-to-many where each record holds `userId` as foreign key and a typed `firstName`. This is bad because it means creating (or removing) a table for each field.
3. Add one table with all possible fields/columns, and every record in it will store the `userId` as foreign key and the data that was entered for that user.

I'm trying to understand if there's a better way to achieve that in relational database or maybe that's the tipping point to switch to a non-relational database.

Comment: Depends on why do you need it and how you are going to use it. Also most of sql databases have some support of json, so the *bad reasons* in #1 are not quite obvious to me.

Answer (score 1):

If you have some restriction on relational database then you can make one column as `BLOB/CLOB` which can store `JSON` so that you can manage the dynamic change in database , as you described. 
But as per the situation you described non relational database is good option for your requirement.As you can add or delete any number of column as per your requirement .